# Static initialization of object

Tags: c++

I have a global object which is declared before main function and a static object inside main.

- Which one of these uses (or do both?) static initialization?
- I've heard that `A obj1` is also called static; why is that?

```
class A { ... };

A obj1;

int main()
{
    static A obj2;
}
```

Comment: This looks like homework, please use the appropriate tag.

Comment: why does it look like homework?

Comment: Because the example looks like a text book one.

Answer (score 4):

`obj1` has static storage. It will be initialized when the program starts.

`obj2` also has static storage because you said so. It will be initialized when `main()` executes the first time.

Comment: for the record: obj1 has static storage because it is a global / namespace member (isn't associated with a function (scope) or class (instance))

Comment: doesn't all static storage objects gets zero-initialized at program startup?

Comment: @user974191: No, the most obvious counter-example would be string literals `"such as this"`.

Comment: @MSalters: `sec (8.5/6) Every object of static storage duration shall be zero-initialized at program startup before any other initialization takes place.`

Comment: @MSalters: That's far from obvious at all. Are you saying that `static int x = 3;` does not end up with the value `3` because it is zero-initialised as a first step?

Comment: Actually, I believe it is undefined exactly when function statics get initialized. It may be done at startup, module load, or when the function is first called.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y The standard says the first time the function is called. But the as-if rule, as always, applies.

Comment: @user974191: True _only_ for variables (such as the `static int x = 3`), because that's what 8.5 covers. See also 3.7.1/1. Storage duration of string literals isn't dictated by 3.7.1/1 but by 2.14.5/8 to /11 (for the different varieties).

Comment: @David Heffernan: Whether the initialization of a static object happens at when main() is first time called or at the point where object is declared depends whether the `obj2` is POD type. I think OP didn't show us the implementation of class.

Comment: @cpx that's down to the compiler and the as-if rule

Answer (score 3):

My first doubt is how precise the question is. If *static initailization* is used with the technical meaning in the standard, it represents *zero-initialization* and initialization of a POD type with *constant expressions* for objects with storage duration, compared with *dynamic initialization* where the initialization of the object with static storage duration is initialized somehow else.

For an illustrative example:

```
// at namespace level
int f();
int a;         // 1 static: zero initialization
int b = 10;    // 2 static: initialization from constant expression
int c = f();   // 3 static (zero initialization)
               // 5 followed by dynamic (result of call to f())
int d = 20;    // 4 static: initialization
int f() { return d; }
int main() {}
```

The number indicates the order of execution of each initialization step. The reason why the compiler considers both static and dynamic initialization is that it sets an order on the execution of the initialization. *static initialization* is executed before *dynamic initialization*, and all *statically initialized* objects are guaranteed to have their value before any *dynamic initialization* starts. That is, the standard guarantees that even if `d` appears after `c` in the previous program, the value of `c` is guaranteed to be `20`.

For objects that require dynamic initialization, they are (conceptually) *zero initialized* during *static initailization*, so during the lifetime of `c`, it is first set to 0, and later reset to `f()` (or 20 in this program). The *conceptually* is due to the fact that if the compiler can infer the final value that the variable will get, it can optimize the *dynamic initialization* away and just perform plain *static initialization* with that final value (in the above code, the compiler could detect that `c` is going to be *dynamically initialized* to 20, and decide to transform it into *static initialization* like `int c = 20;` in a conforming implementation. In that case steps 3 and 5 in the code above would be merged into a single step 3.

In the case of a local variable with static storage duration, the standard does not use the terms *static/dynamic initialization*, but the descriptions require the same behavior from the program. Local variables with static duration are *zero-initialized* or POD initialized with constant expressions when (or before) the block is entered for the first time (as with *static initialization*), while for the rest of the initializations are performed the first time that control passes over through it's declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Focusing on C++ only, you also need to consider initialization of static members. 
It concerns static members of a class.
For example, when you have:

```
class A {
  // declaration of i as a static member of class A
  static int i;
};

// initialization of static member outside class A
int A::i = 42;
```

Comment: No, that's not true at all. That your `i` is a class member doesn't have anything to do with its static initialisation behaviour, and it doesn't differ from the OP's case all that much at all.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with pointing out that the keyword `static` applies to class members in C++, or that an equivalent does not exist for C structs.  This is a terminology question, so if one is to do a survey of the scope of meaning of "static" it's good to cover all the bases.  Static class members, static class methods, etc.  +0.5 for mentioning that, and +0.5 for the Douglas Adams allusion.

Comment: @jHackTheRipper: The title isn't the question. Note that this answer has completely transformed since my initial comment. It's not so bad now, but it still doesn't answer the question (which is not about class members at all).

Comment: @HostileFork: And I don't see what C has to do with anything, but I suppose if you'll give half an upvote just for writing "42" then you'll upvote anything!

Comment: @TomalakGeretkal People with 37.6k rep should have better things to do than downvote zero-scored conversational answers on slightly vague questions.  Want to improve it?  Use the edit button, that's what it's for.

Comment: @HostileFork: There's nothing conversational about it, and this is not a vague question: the question is very clearly stated (David managed to understand it), and this answer has _nothing at all to do with it_. And the current score of a question or answer should have absolutely no bearing whatsoever on what vote you cast. Also, the reason I have 37.6k is because I have nothing better to do than to contribute constructively to Stack Overflow

Comment: @HostileFork - On the contrary, a rep of 37.6k is probably a sign that someone doesn't have anything better to do ;-)  (No offence intended Tomalak, I'm just jelous)

Comment: @Benj: None taken. ;) Hyperbole and dramatics aside, I actually multitask rather effectively.

Comment: @TomalakGeretkal your email address on your website bounces.  "Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently: fromsitewelcome-112009@kera.name Technical details of permanent failure:  Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the recipient domain."

Answer (score 1):

Both of these variables are static:

`obj1` is a non-local static variable which will be initialized when the program starts.

`obj2` is a local static variable which will be initialised when the function is first called.

Scott Meyers in his book "Effective C++" recommends accessing local static variables through functions as opposed to using non-local static variables.  Doing so avoids the so called static initialization order problem where one variable can reference another which may not have been initialized yet because of the arbitrary order in which initialization occurs.

Comment: +1 The "static initialization order fiasco" http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14